# Print result of Fabric command

Tags: django, shell, deployment, fabric

I would like to redirect the output of the Fabric command

```
print local("git add .")
```

so that I make sure that everything is working properly.  Is there a way to pipe the results of this command to the console?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should already see the output of the command in the console since that's the default behaviour. If you need to customize it, please have a look at the [managing output](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/usage/output_controls.html) documentation section.

Besides this, there's an ongoing effort to use the `logging` module ([issue #57](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/57)) that should provide more options like logging to a file, but that hasn't been merged into the trunk branch yet.

Comment: interesting... `git add .` does not seem to return anything but when I try other commands they do pipe to console.  Thanks for the tip about log also.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Also, since you know a lot about Fabric, I did have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392540/local-setting-for-installed-apps-using-fabric if you would be kind enough to look at if possible